# JavaScript typeof should be number but returns string

Tags: javascript, typeof

my problem is that I want to print out only the properties of my object which are strings. but when I check for the type of the property it's returning string also for a number..

Here's my code:

```
var languages = {
    english: "Hello!",
    french: "Bonjour!",
    notALanguage: 4,
    spanish: "Hola!"
};

for(var prop in languages){
    console.log(typeof prop);   
}
```

The output is:

```
string
string
string
string
```

I'm sure it's just an easy to solve issue but I can't understand why `typeof` returns string for the property `notALanguage`...

Comment: `typeof languages[prop]`...

Comment: for(var prop in languages){
    console.log(typeof languages[prop]);   
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`prop` will be a string representation of the property *name*.

You want to test `typeof languages[prop]`

Answer (score 5):

When you use `for var .. in ..` you're iterating over the **keys**. Therefore it's effectively doing:

```
console.log(typeof 'english');
console.log(typeof 'french');
console.log(typeof 'notALanguage');
console.log(typeof 'spanish');
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I upvoted your answer but i will accept Quentin's answer because his tip solved my problem..